# CGAL ConvexHull and Eigen

Tags: c++11, cgal, eigen3

How can I use my own my own data with CGAL for constructing the convex hull. Especially I would like to use an `Eigen3` type and somehow wrap it that CGAL can directly use it, without copying all `Eigen3` `Vector2d` into the CGAL `Point_2` class ?

The eigen types all have member function `.x() , .y(), .z()`

Can somebody give an introduction how to achieve this, [the Kernel Extension tutorial](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Kernel_23/index.html#sectionextensiblekernel) is so hard to understand....

**Update**
I came up so far with a custom iterator which stores a reference to a `Eigen::Matrix` (pointer or `Eigen::Ref` class ) and iterates over the columns which are 2x1 vectors. thats only one part of the puzzle: Secondly, I managed to simply typedef `Point_2` as `Eigen::Vector2d` and use the kernel extension tutorial (see above), but I still did not figure out how to put together the whole puzzle? (I post the code tomorrow)

Comment: You are right that the CGAL manual is somewhat hard to understand. Can you be more specific about what in the manual is not understandable? I suggest you edit you question, instead of replying in a comment.

Comment: Copying points (pairs of double) is going to be negligible. A relatively simple thing you could do is create a traits class, following the requirements of convex hull, with your point type, and for each predicate convert to cgal point type and call cgal's predicate. A sensible compiler will inline everything and cgal's point type won't even appear in the compiled binary.

Comment: @ Gliss, you mean http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Convex_hull_2/classConvexHullTraits__2.html, 
where do I need to inject this?  Thanks a lot?

Comment: @Gabriel Yes, this. You pass an instance of it as last argument to the convex hull functions apparently.

Comment: Have you found a solution to your problem, eventually? If so, can you please write a self-answer to your post? That might help users with same question.

Comment: yup I try to find the code in a few days!